# Multiple mouse events not working when binding innerHTML

Tags: angular, mouseevent, innerhtml

I'm trying to auto-generate a complex/interactive SVG image in angular, but it seems like there is a problem in the event bindings.

I've tried with [click] event only and it works fine and the event is triggered. also, [mouseout] event works fine on its own or with [click] event.
but when I add [mouseenter] or [mouseover] no other events are triggered.
I tried to leave only one event directly bonded to the element and listen to [mouseout] and [click] using @HostListener Decorator but it doesn't work either!

I think the [innerHTML] has to do something about this but it's very important and I couldn't remove it. simply I don't know what are the sub-elements of this group, they are dynamically generated or uploaded by the user as a simple SVG generated by adobe illustrator so I'm using a js to XML converter to generate the internal objects of the group.

```html
  <svg>
    <g id="group">
      <g *ngFor="let object of array"
        (mouseenter)="hoverStarted($event, object)"
        (mouseout)="hoverEnded($event, object)"
        (click)="objectClick(object)"
        [innerHTML]="getObjectInternalSvgString(object)"
        >
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

I expect that all of the mouse events [mouseenter, mouseout, click] to be triggered, but only [mouseenter] is being triggered.
and when I remove [mouseenter] both [mouseout] and [click] work flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that works great!

first, I removed the innerHTML binding from the group and added a `TemplateReference` identifier.

then in the `.ts` file I added `ViewChildren` with a `QueryList` for this identifier, and only injecting the innerHTML once after view init.

```html
  <svg>
    <g id="group">
      <g *ngFor="let object of array"
        (mouseenter)="hoverStarted($event, object)"
        (mouseout)="hoverEnded($event, object)"
        (click)="objectClick(object)"
        #groups
        >
      </g>
    </g>
  </svg>
```

```js
@ViewChildren('groups') objectGroups: QueryList<ElementRef>;
ngAfterViewInit() {
   const objectArray = this.objectGroups.toArray();
   for ( const index in objectArray ) {
      objectArray[index].nativeElement.innerHTML = this.getObjectInternalSvgStringByIndex(index)
   }
}
```

and now all the mouse events works flawlessly.